# lubridate year date in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

how can you create a data frame with twelve rows and three columns. First to select random year in 3000:9999 range.

The requirement of the three columns are: The first variable (column) should be dates (last day of each month in selected year) the second variable should be non-empty, and unique, strings (characters), and the third variable should be random permutation of 1:12 integers?

Is there a way to randomize the year within the as.Date function or any other better way to do it? how can i use lubridate to get the last day of each month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
library(lubridate)

dates <- ceiling_date(date(paste(sample(3000:9999, 1), 1:12, "1", sep = "-")), "months") - 1
strings <- sample(LETTERS, 12)
numbers <- sample(1:12, 12)

df <- data.frame(dates, strings, numbers)

> print(df)
        dates strings numbers
1  9366-01-31       U       6
2  9366-02-28       J       2
3  9366-03-31       T       5
4  9366-04-30       G       1
5  9366-05-31       I       7
6  9366-06-30       L      10
7  9366-07-31       H       8
8  9366-08-31       R       3
9  9366-09-30       B      11
10 9366-10-31       V      12
11 9366-11-30       E       4
12 9366-12-31       F       9
```

Comment: thanks! why are you ceiling_date fucntion? doesn't it take a date-time object and rounds it up to the nearest integer value of the specified time unit?

Comment: It's to get the last day of the month. Since not all months have the same final date I found it easier to just generate the first day of the month as a date and then round it up. By the way, `ceiling_date` rounds to the upper boundary (the first day of the next month), so you have to subtract one to get the last day of the month.

Comment: Gotcha! thanks. this is actually an easier way to achieve the last day of the month.